# Does there exist a scriptable Display Manager that allows me to login a user?

Tags: display-manager

I've been looking at Display Managers like SDDM, GDM and LightDM, but it doesn't seem as if they support a non-interactive login.

I want to issue a command to have it login to one of the users, without requiring the user to enter a password on the GUI.

One usecase is logging in my son or my daughter on their computer, when I myself am logged in via SSH.

Another usecase is logging myself in, when I am close to a computer, for example with bluetooth proximity.

I need to use a command like

dm_login username

Another option is to launch an Xorg server with xinit on another tty, but I think it will be much cleaner having a scriptable Display Manager.

EDIT: I'm on NixOS, but I could use any distro to solve this problem.

EDIT2: I know all of them supports auto-login, but there are multiple users on the system.

Comment: Are you using any particular Unix?

Comment: You could temporarily add a /etc/sddm.conf.d/99-autologin.conf there containing the user you want to log in, then `systemctl restart sddm`. (Maybe `systemctl reload sddm` suffices)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think he's looking for some sort of setup that he can authenticate a login attempt with another user account as the "authenticating third-party / agent". It's just that he doesn't need/want a mechanism for the user who is logging in to send a login request, but simply expect the user to call him and say "dad, let me use the computer!". (I suppose what you suggest sort of works though; just not exactly convenient)